# Shallow copy behavior in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, shallow-copy, copy-on-write

Lots of people bump into unexpected shallow copy behavior when they start off in Python, and I'd like to make sure I don't make any of those mistakes in MATLAB (with which I have less experience).

I read this article about [object behaviors in MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/copying-objects.html#brtm8vo) and I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427288/is-it-possible-to-get-a-reference-to-a-matrix-in-matlab) that pertains to pointer/handle behavior. Are there any situations where `isa(obj, 'handle')` would return false but you would still encounter the situation where modification of `obj` would result in the modification of another variable (to my knowledge, any argument modification by a function call should trigger a [copy on write and duplicate the variable in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735841/initializing-a-ublas-vector-from-a-c-array/1735997#1735997))?

Is this a complete understanding of "shallow copy"-like behavior in MATLAB? Are there any additional caveats to standard value object copy behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A value class can contain a handle class, and if you modify it you will change the instance of the handle class. For example (note that `containers.Map` is a built-in class that is a handle - nothing special about it, I just chose it for convenience:

```
>> a = containers.Map; a('hello') = 1;
>> b = struct('field1', 1, 'field2', a);
>> isa(b, 'handle')
ans =
  logical
   0
>> b.field2('hello') = 2;
>> a('hello')
ans =
     2
```

So `b` is a struct (which has value semantics), but one of its fields contains a `containers.Map`, which is a handle and has reference semantics. When you modify that field, you also change `a`, which is another reference to the underlying `containers.Map`.

Comment: Excellent answer. I hadn't considered that edge case at all. I really appreciate the code demonstration of the specific questions asked

Comment: Glad my answer helped. It's not really an edge case though - it's an example of a more general issue. `b` needn't have been a struct - it could have been a cell array with `a` as an element, or an instance of a value class with `a` as a property. It could have been a function handle that had captured `a` in its workspace, and so on. And `a` may have been hidden several levels deep within `b`.

Comment: Though in this case `isa(b.field2, 'handle')` returns true. So you can always know in advance that this would happen.

Comment: @CrisLuengo That's true in the case where `b` is a struct and the handle is stored as a field, but it's not always possible - for example, if the handle was stored in a private property of a value class `b`. The handle could be modified by a method of `b`, causing other references to it to change, but you'd have no access to the handle in order to verify it in the way you're describing.

Comment: @SamRoberts: Hum, that's interesting. And surprising. I guess you're right about that.