# Handler to fundamental type variable

Tags: matlab

Is it possible in MATLAB  to have a reference to a fundamental type without wrapping it in a class?

Example:

```
A = 5;
RefToA = GetRef(A);
RedToA.Value = 10;
A
```

This should prints 10 not 5.

Are there something like `GetRef` and  `.Value`?

Comment: Short answer: No. Longer answer: basically already addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3427288/52738).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes I do ask for a reference. I thought it called handler in MATLAB.