# Allocate array of complex numbers of value 0+0i?

Tags: matlab

This command

```
Y1 = repmat(0+0i, 10, 1);
```

appears to create an array of doubles, while this command

```
Y2 = repmat(0.0001+0.0001i, 10, 1);
```

correctly creates an array of complex double.

Is there a way in MatLab to allocate for later use an array of complex doubles with magnitudes of zero or am I required to start with very small magnitudes as I've done above??

Comment: From a few days ago: [How Do I Prevent MATLAB from Dropping the "complex" Attribute of an Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327951/how-do-i-prevent-matlab-from-dropping-the-complex-attribute-of-an-array).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`zeros(10,1,'like',1i)`

I found it pretty quickly by looking at the help file for `zeros`.

Comment: I suspect this is the answer MatLab's language spec would provide. (Is there a language spec? I'm too new to know.) Anyway, thanks!

Comment: For those using older versions of Marlab, I believe this [works for R2013a+](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html). The solution from @jez should work regardless of version.

Answer (score 4):

`complex(zeros(10,1))` seems to do the trick for me.   The problem is that your literal `0i` actually evaluates to real `0`, whereas `complex(0)` would be the way to get a scalar with explicit zero real and imaginary components.

Comment: Unless the interpreter is clever, this will probably initialize a matrix of reals, then convert to doubles, which might be rather wasteful if OPs actual data is of considerable size.

Comment: Good point. And this is Matlab we're talking about, so I seriously doubt that the interpreter is that clever.

Comment: Yes, the 'Tips' section of complex sort of suggests the problem I ran into. That said complex(0) or complex(0,0) does seem to work. Thanks!